# Regex word boundaries capturing wrong words

Tags: c#, regex

I am having some difficulties trying to get my simple `Regex` statement in C# working the way I want it to.

If I have a long string and I want to find the word "executive" but **NOT** "executives" I thought my regex would look something like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", "executive");
```

This, however, is still matching on inputs that contain only `executives` and not `executive` (singular).

I thought word boundaries in regex, when used at the beginning and end of your regex text, would specify that you *only* want to match that word and not any other form of that word?

Edit: To clarify whats happening, I am trying to find all of the `Notes` among `Students` that contain the word `executive` and ignoring words that simply contain "executive". As follows:

```
var studentMatches =
    Students.SelectMany(o => o.Notes)
        .Where(c => Regex.Match(c.NoteText, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", query)).Success).ToList();
```

where `query` would be "executive" in this case.

Whats strange is that while the above code will match on `executives` even though I don't want it to, the following code will **not** (aka it does what I am expecting it to do):

```
foreach (var stu in Students)
{
    foreach (var note in stu.Notes)
    {

        if (Regex.IsMatch(note.NoteText, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", query)))
            Console.WriteLine(stu.LastName);
    }
}
```

Why would a nested for loop with the same regex code produce accurate matches while a linq expression seems to want to return anything that contains the word I am searching for?

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes, I have read over that and their example of \b4\b is effectively the same as what I have, only their example does NOT match "44" whereas mine does (executive vs executives)

Comment: What type of pattern is returning for executives? I can't get it to occur given your code.

Comment: @Tom I have edited my post for clarification

Comment: I still suspect some other issue not related to regex. I would put a breakpoint on the line where the regex occurs for the `var studentMatches` and see what the value of query is.

Comment: @Tom query as in "executive"? Or were you referring to NoteText? Because it is a console application and I am manually typing "executive" as the search query every time. Could perhaps calling Trim() on my input help?

Answer (score 1):

Your linq query produces the correct result. What you see is what you have written.

Let's give proper names to make it clear

```
var noteMatches = Students.SelectMany(student => student.Notes)
    .Where(note => Regex.Match(note.NoteText, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", query)).Success)
    .ToList();
```

In this query after executing `SelectMany` we received a flattened list of all notes. Thus was lost the information about which note belonged to which student.

Meanwhile, in the sample code with `foreach` loops you output information about the student.

I can assume that you need a query like the following

```
var studentMatches = Students.Where(student => student.Notes
        .Any(note => Regex.IsMatch(note.NoteText, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", query))))
    .ToList();
```

However, it is not clear what result you want to obtain if the same student will have notes containing both *executive* and *executives*.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.